# How to substitute each item in this list?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to detect and change lists of the following format. Input string

```
bla bla
* a
* list
* here
bla * bla
bl**a
* another
* list
```

Desired output:

```
bla bla
LIST
+ a
+ list
+ here
END
bla * bla
bl**a
LIST
+ another
+ list 
END
```

Working on this, I realised that I should use another kind of parser and that regex is not the best tool for the job. Still, it made me curious and I'd like to know if this problem is solvable with regular expressions. I can detect the list and add the LIST/END tokens:

```
s/((^\* .*\n){2,})/LIST\n\1\nEND/gm;
```

However, how would I end change the individual items of the list? Is there some way to use these capture groups that are quantified? Doing another pass with `s/^\* /+ /g` is not possible, since I'm only interested in lists of two items or more.

Comment: Regex is part of the solution, but not **the solution**. You want write a program that works through your input, detects the beginning of a list, the end of a list, and then does what you want. The trick is to do this line by line. You have several options for every line. You can be at the start of a list, at the end of a list, inside a list or not inside a list.

Comment: Repeated capturing groups wouldn't work because they only hold the last occurence of the match : matching `(\w)+` over `abc` will have the first capturing group holding `c`.

Comment: @simbabque Yes this is exactly what I meant. Sorry for being unclear. I have a working solution with a "parser". I'm curious to expand my regex knowledge.

Comment: You could probably make it with lookarounds to distinguish whether you're at the start, middle or end of a list (just check whether you're preeceeding or following another list item) ; the three cases only match a single list item so you can use capturing group to replace fixed patterns in the list items

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is indeed solvable with Perl regular expressions (regexes).
A nested `s///` does the trick:

```
$/=undef;
$_=<DATA>;
s{((^\* .*\n){2,})}{
    "LIST\n$1END\n"=~s{^\*}{+}mgr;
}gme;
print ;

__DATA__
bla bla
* a
* list
* here
bla * bla
bl**a
* another
* list
```

---

```
bla bla
LIST
+ a
+ list
+ here
END
bla * bla
bl**a
LIST
+ another
+ list
END
```

Comment: Well technically that's Perl, not regex. ;)

Comment: @simbabque regex term in the question refers to Perl regex, I think, not to what SO tag embraces. But I fixed the answer anyway.

Comment: @wolfrevokcats: Awesome. +1

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to read the data into a hash and then write out the data again with any new formatting attached:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);

my %structured_list;
my @keys;
my $key;

# read data in storing lists under associated keys as array references
while (my $line = readline(*DATA)) {
  chomp $line;

  if ($line =~ /^\*/) {
    # this could be simplified
    push @{$structured_list{$key}}, $line =~ s/^\*\s*//gr;
  }
  else {
    $key = $line;
    push @keys, $key;
    $structured_list{$key} = [];
  }
}

# read keys back out in order
foreach my $list_key (@keys) {
  if (@{$structured_list{$list_key}}) {
    say $list_key;
    say "LIST";
    foreach my $val (@{$structured_list{$list_key}}) {
      say "+ $val";
    }
    say "END";
  }
  else {
   say $list_key;
  }
}

__DATA__
bla bla
* a
* list
* here
bla * bla
bl**a
* another
* list
```

outputs:

```
➜  perl test.pl
bla bla
LIST
+ a
+ list
+ here
END
bla * bla
bl**a
LIST
+ another
+ list
END
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and sorry for being unclear. I have a working solution with a line-by-line "parser". I'm curious to expand my regex knowledge.